# Reading gmail using Rmail

Tags: email

When I try to connect to my gmail account *foo@gmail.com* (password: *foopassword*), using the following setting:

```
(setq rmail-primary-inbox-list '("pop://foo:foopassword@pop.gmail.com:995"))
```

I get the following error:

```
movemail: mailbox `pop://foo@pop.gmail.com:995': cannot open: Name or service not known
```

And when I set the variable like this:

```
(setq rmail-primary-inbox-list '("pop://foo@gmail.com:foopassword@pop.gmail.com:995"))
```

I get the following:

```
movemail: mailbox `pop://foo@pop.gmail.com:995': cannot open: Name or service not known
```

So what do I need to connect to read my gmail messages using Rmail?

Answer (score 1):

"Name or service not known" always means that a program tried to open a network connection, but the address of the destination is incorrect (it couldn't be resolved using DNS). Look in your email provider's help files or tech support for the correct address.

Comment: How would you connect to your email using Rmail, give me an example if you can please. Doesn't have to be gmail, any free mail server would do.

Comment: Which version of emacs? The movemail shipped with Emacs 26.1 does not enable pop by default. The easiest solution is probably to install Gnu Mailutils <https://mailutils.org>, which has a far more featureful movemail.

Comment: @rpluim that's the one I'm using. and still doesn't work.

Comment: You're doing it right, but you have the wrong address. I don't know what address gmail uses, but "pop.gmail.com" is obviously the wrong one.